# PHP - Is there a way to calculate regular expressions (regex) designed for your need?

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to write the regex to search for image tags within a string, then to count them using either 'count' or 'substr_count'

**EG:** [image1], [image2] etc etc..

I'm an absolute rookie with regex so it's pretty confusing to me. Before anyone asks, yes I have done a little research into it, but I was just curious as to whether or not there is any shortcuts that are out there that myself and anyone else reading this may be missing out on.

I have also found the https://regex101.com/ however am clueless as to where to go from there.

**My efforts for the example above are:**

```
'~(\[image([\d])+\]~i'
```

and ..

```
'#[^a-z0-9.]#i'
```

If someone could show me how to search for the above, or point me in the right direction to a programming gold-mine it'd be more than appreciated.

Cheers,
Rich

Comment: `preg_match_all` returns the number of occurrences, see the php manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Comment: I'll try this, thanks. Would you be able to confirm if my regex's are correct?

Comment: Please post a clear sample of input/output . i.e.: "__i have this__" and  "__I need this__".

Comment: The first seems good, I don't understand what you are trying to do with the second.

Comment: Get anything within the brackets that is text + number. EG: [image + number]. Am I completely off track? :/

Comment: I have, Pedro? I've explained what I'm searching for and what my efforts are thus far.

Comment: @Filthy_Rich: indeed, since `[....]` is used to delimit a character class, `[` and `]` are not seen as literal characters. I'm wondering you wrote this since you escaped them in the first pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [preg_match_all](http://preg_match_all), i.e.:

```
$string = <<< LOL
some text with image1 and another
part of that contains image2
yet another image3
LOL;

preg_match_all('/(image\d+)/i', $string, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches[1]); $i++) {
    echo $matches[1][$i]."\n";
}
```

---

**OUTPUT:**

```
image1
image2
image3
```

---

**DEMO:**

http://ideone.com/cQymaV

Comment: How would I go about using this technique to count the total number of [image + number] tags?

Answer (score 0):

The [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) function already returns the number of occurrences, you don't need to use count or something else:

```
if (false !== $count = preg_match_all('~\[image\d+]~i', $text))
    echo $count;
```